# How to set item weight Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

How to set item weight `Navigation Drawer`? Necessary for the elements to stretch in width to height.
Can this be done at all?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the 20dp what ever the size you want

```
app:itemIconSize="20dp"
```